# SiteMapResolve does not fire

Tags: asp.net

I am getting trouble that SiteMapResolve fires on some pages and doesn't on other.

This is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(this.ChangeMapPath);
}

private SiteMapNode ChangeMapPath(Object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    if (SiteMap.CurrentNode != null)
    {
        // Clone the current node and all of its relevant parents.
        SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);
        SiteMapNode tempNode = currentNode;

        if (clientId != 0 && tempNode.Title.Equals("Client Notes"))
        {
            tempNode.Url = tempNode.Url + EncryptQueryString("ParentId=" + clientId.ToString());
        }
        if (clientId != 0 && tempNode.ParentNode != null && (tempNode.ParentNode.Title.Equals("Client Contacts")))
        {
            tempNode.ParentNode.Url = tempNode.ParentNode.Url + EncryptQueryString("ParentId=" + clientId.ToString());
        }
        else if (tempNode.ParentNode != null)
            tempNode.ParentNode.Url = tempNode.ParentNode.Url;

        return currentNode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try replace your code

```
SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(this.ChangeMapPath);
```

to

```
foreach (SiteMapProvider mapProvider in SiteMap.Providers)
{
    mapProvider.SiteMapResolve += ChangeMapPath;
}
```

Comment: of course you need to use `mapProvider.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(ChangeMapPath);` for .net < 2 :)

Comment: Looks like someone used this code. I want to explain possible reason why it will work when other fails. The main reason is that you may have misconfiguration of SiteMap. Example: you may have several SiteMapProviders and mark one SiteMapProvider as main. Also you can specify another SiteMapProvider for SiteMap. In this case when you add handler you actually add handler to main provider.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but just in case anyone else is still dealing with this issue, the following solution works for me.

It appears that there is an issue with SiteMapResolveEventHandler not ever being removed, so the first event handler that is added, will be the one that gets called after that point.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2012/11/29/asp-net-case-study-sitemapresolveeventhandler-memory-leakage/

So, you can do exactly as the original poster has done, but you also need to add the following to each page that adds the SiteMapResolveEventHandler.

```
protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMap.Provider.SiteMapResolve -= new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(this.ChangeMapPath);
}
```

It should call the appropriate handler on each page if you have forced the removal on previous pages.

Alternatively, instead of using the Page_Unload, you could place the

```
SiteMap.Provider.SiteMapResolve -= new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(this.ChangeMapPath);
```

line of code at the beginning of the ChangeMapPath method.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me better and easier to understand / maintain:

Create an interface with a handler method:

```
public interface ISiteMapResolver
{
    SiteMapNode SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e);
}
```

subscribe to each event in the `Application_Start` method in global.asax

```
foreach (SiteMapProvider siteMapProvider in SiteMap.Providers)
    siteMapProvider.SiteMapResolve += Provider_SiteMapResolve;
}
```

Then implement this method

```
SiteMapNode Provider_SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{  
     var handler = e.Context.CurrentHandler as ISiteMapResolver;
         return handler != null ? handler.SiteMapResolve(sender, e) : null;
}
```

This way you can implement `ISiteMapResolver`in each page you are interested to modify the node, e.g.

```
public SiteMapNode SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    if (SiteMap.CurrentNode == null) return null;
    var node = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);

    node.Url += "?productId=" + ProductId; // Access page property, no problem. Page_Load event already fired.
    note.Title = "Product " + Product;

    // Modify node.ParentNode here if needed.

    return node;
}
```